# "on" or "at" par

Tags: grammar

Which is correct: "on par" or "at par"? I'm not sure if "on" or "at" is appropriate, or if both are appropriate depending on the usage. Can someone please give some guidance?

1. His cooking skills are "at" par with professional chefs.
2. His cooking skills are "on" par with professional chefs.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+at+par+with%2Care+on+par+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20at%20par%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20on%20par%20with%3B%2Cc0    I'd choose ***on par with*** in your case.

Comment: **at par** if you are golfing and discussing the score, **on par** otherwise.

Comment: " . . . on pare with [those of] professional chefs."

Answer (score 1):

The OED, sense 2, proposes *on a par* - meaning 'on an equal footing with'.

2. More generally: equality of value or standing; an equal footing, a level. Now chiefly in on a par.

Comment: I agree - in my ideolectic neck of the woods, it's conversationally commonplace to say something is *on a par with [some supposed nonpareil]*. Without the article it sounds much more like a starchy legal/financial usage.

Answer (score -1):

It is helpful here, I think, to examine the etymology of the word *par*, and specifically its form used in golf, which is a noun.  Apparently in UK English it means `an amount which is taken as an average or mean`, that is, an "expectation". This is the meaning, I would speculate, that became used in golf [circa 1898](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=par). An "expected" number of strokes to reach a hole.

Thus, *par* seems to really be a quantity, not a quality.  And indeed, your example, food, is qualitative.

### If you must use a preposition (*at*, *in*...)

We say a golfer scores "at par", because literally his numerical score is *at* a certain point, namely the number that is par.  "On par" might work to, but it is not *as* correct to say a number is *on* another number, but it is correct to say a score is *at* a number. So *at* is better for numbers.

But you are talking about food, suggesting that *par* is a quality, so it is totally a colloquial misuse of the word in the first place, so since both expressions are equally used (colloquially), then they are equally correct/incorrect.  I would use "at par", to at least use the term consistently with golf, for what it is worth.

### Maybe drop the preposition

Since par is a quantity, we could also say the golfer "scores par" or "his score **is** par".  You are concerned about the preposition, but to show some quality is equal to the expectation you can say:

`"(The quality of) H/his cooking skill(s) is/are par with professional chefs.`

There, that sounds quite nice actually, eliminates the problematic preposition, and maintains the qualitative nature of the statement.

See *par* on [wiktionary.com](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/par#Noun)

Comment: I can't find the "sense 2" of par on the OED as mentioned in another post, without a link citation.  I linked the OED I was referring to in my post.  I'll bet people saw the word "golf" in my response and down voted, but in all reality, the term is not very current, *except* for golf, and that's the only reason it is even used by anyone < 100 years old.  You used it informally, not in a "starchy legal/financial" way, so it is appropriate to analyze your question from that point of view, working backwards from golf.